# I am trying out to do the "Count Reverse Pairs" and I can't understand why parentesis() are necessary on this line

Tags: java, math

I know that addition is commutative therefore I want to perform a storing operation with shorthand operation `+=` at line 46 but the answer differs only when I put the parenthesis, also when when I don't put parenthesis I get wrong answer.

The line is in the merge function.

CODE:

```java
public class ProblemA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer> (Arrays.asList(1, 3, 2, 3, 1));
        int n = arr.size();
        //calling mergesort 
        int total = countPair(arr, n);
        System.out.println(total);
    }

    public static int countPair(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int n) {
        int total = mergeSort(arr, 0, n - 1);
        return total;
    }

    public static int mergeSort(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int low, int high) {
        //termination condition
        if (low >= high) return 0;
        //firstly we'll disassociate the elements of array on elementary level
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        //we'll store our count value inside the counter variable 
        int inv = mergeSort(arr, low, mid);
        inv += mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, high);
        inv += merge(arr, low, mid, high);
        return inv;
    }
    public static int merge(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int low, int mid, int high) {
        //AIM: make a double loop and traverse through the elements and increase the right side pointer
        //whenever condition (arr[i]>2*arr[j] is satisfied)
        //int i = 0;
        int total = 0;
        int j = mid + 1;
        for (int i = low; i<= mid; i++) {
            //looping till we run out the right hand side or condition is not satisfied
            while (j<= high && arr.get(i) > 2 * arr.get(j)) {
                j++;
            } **
            * total += (j - (mid + 1)); ** * //parenthesis error here
        }

        //Now we can move to merging part
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
        int left = low, right = mid + 1;
        while (left<= mid && right<= high) {
            if (arr.get(left)<= arr.get(right)) {
                temp.add(arr.get(left++));
            } else {
                temp.add(arr.get(right++));
            }
        }

        //for the last right or left remaining element 
        while (left<= mid) {
            temp.add(arr.get(left++));
        }
        while (right<= high) {
            temp.add(arr.get(right++));
        }

        //now we can copy the remaining elements from temp list to arr
        for (int i = low, k = 0; i<= high; i++) {
            arr.set(i, temp.get(k++));
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT(with parenthesis) "total += (j-(mid+1))":

```
2
```

OUTPUT(without parenthesis) "total += j-mid+1":

```
16
```

Comment: "the answer differs" from what? "when I put the parenthesis" Which pair? There are two. Please make two separate [mre], of both versions of your code which you want to discuss. Also please show the results you get in contrast to those you expect please.

Comment: I added the output part. Apologies.

Comment: Subtracting the sum of two things is not the same as subtracting the first and adding the second. I do not see why you expect this to have the same result. I'd only expect the same result with and without the outer pair, but the inner pair is obviously necessary. Please explain the math you expect with examples of `total` and `mid` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because if you use parenthesis, java will decide which expression you want to evaluate first. If you don't use parenthesis then everything goes executed from left to right.
Example:

```
int total=1;
int total1=1;
int total2=1;
total+=total1-total2+1;
System.out.println(total);
```

Output : 2

The reason is here, expression got evaluated as total=total+total1-total2+1;
i.e. total=1+1-1+1=2;

For parenthesis based expression, it gets evaluated first & then others:-

```
int total=1;
int total1=1;
int total2=1;
total+=(total1-(total2+1));
System.out.println(total);
```

Output : 0 ,  evaluation will happen like below :-

```
total=total+(1-(1+1));
total=1+(1-(2));
total=1+(-1);
total=0;
```

Reference : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html